# How to modify a label to a field in checkout page?

Tags: onepage-checkout

I need to edit a label in a field in the checkout page.

I should have an extension (*Firecheckout*) to manage checkout page.

In fact, the checkout page has an url like *domainname.com/firecheckout*

In user manual (http://templates-master.com/firecheckout-user-manual#Different%20layout%20type) you can see that you can easily change a label

[image]

But in my platform those field checkout fields are not filled in "checkout fields" menu, nor in standard configuration view, nor in main website view

[image]

How could I change a label?

Answer (score 0):

1. After edit the lable.
2. You can go to: System -> Cache Management -> Fush Magento Cache.

If it is not. Please provide more information.

Comment: In my platform I can see *checkout fields* but those fields are as image above and they are not those I see on page *domainname.com/firecheckout*. Where should I change those fields?